# SQL Server 2012 Query - Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this script

```
select  * 
from psPatDiscounts 
where cancelflag = '0' 
and refdate between  '2014-01-01 14:03:00' 
and '2014-01-31 14:03:00'
group by FK_psPatRegisters
```

however, after running this script it gives me this error message :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'psPatDiscounts.PK_TRXNO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `SELECT *` expands to `SELECT Col1, Col2, ...` for all available columns in your table(s). The error message is telling you that if you `GROUP BY FK_psPatRegisters` you can't include any other columns in the `SELECT` part of the query unless they're wrapped in an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To have a group by, you need a select column and an aggregate function, something like this:

```
select  psPatRegisters.ID, Count(*) 
  from psPatDiscounts 
 where cancelflag = '0' 
   and refdate between  '2014-01-01 14:03:00' 
   and '2014-01-31 14:03:00'  group by psPatRegisters.ID
```

In this case Count(*) is the aggregate function and it is grouped by ID

Answer (score 0):

You can only include select columns which are referenced, as your error indicates, in a `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function.

You either need to include more columns in your `GROUP BY`, or reduce your `SELECT *` to `SELECT FK_psPatRegisters`.

```
SELECT FK_psPatRegisters
FROM psPatDiscounts 
WHERE cancelflag = '0' AND refdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01 14:03:00' AND '2014-01-31 14:03:00'
GROUP BY FK_psPatRegisters
```

In essence, the issue is that a single cell can't include multiple values. So to group by only one column and select others, you need to specify how to handle those multiple values.